# Best way of connecting two meshes, one with many faces

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I am trying to model a gas mask. I've made three separate meshes and planned on attaching them to the main head mesh. Those three comprise of the two lenses and frontal gas mask filter. But I've run into a problem with that.

I'm unsure of the best of attaching a mesh with many faces to another mesh with less faces. I don't know what the most efficient way of doing this would be.

[image][image]

Comment: as explained by Lukasz-40sth, to join all these objects and make only one object, press ctrl J. Now you can work your topology to make only one mesh but are you sure this is necessary? In reality these 4 parts are separate objects so you it would be logical to keep the meshes apart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A typical subdivision approach would avoid using meshes of different densities where possible, and rely on Catmull-Clark subdivision to create curvatures/circles..

Any (6+)-gon will make a reasonable circle under subdiv. Often made from 4 quads:

- Select all quads
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> Dissolve central vertex
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> Poke single face
  -<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> Bevel central vertex
- Shipped Add-On, Loop Tools > Circle the result

[image]

Then, with extrusions, and some rotations/scales around Custom Orientations, you can model something like this mask without having to reduce topology to match between densities.

[image]

If you do really need to match areas of significantly different detail, often, to avoid fiddly hand work, you can model at a lower level of subdivision than your intended result, apply one level of subdiv, and continue modeling from there.

Comment: ..and as moonboots and Lukasz  have said, unless you have constraints such as 3D printing, separate parts are usually best modeled as separate parts. No harm.

Answer (score 2):

With separate objects as described by you the best way is <kbd>CTRL+J</kbd> or **Combine**. Provided that all your objects are modelled as you want them. Other ways require heavy retopologizing.